# Mouse events not called in VB WPF, does z-order matter?

Tags: wpf, vb.net

There are many explanation in google, but I still struggling to implement mouse events.

- I have tried to use `MouseEnter="Canvas1_MouseEnter"` in canvas properties, but it doesn't work.
- I tried to add manually, [image: add manually]. it doesn't work.
- I also tried to use `AddHandler Canvas1.MouseEnter, AddressOf Canvas1_MouseEnter` in `Private Sub main_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles main.Loaded` method, it doesn't work too.
- Then I tried to move `AddHandler Canvas1.MouseEnter, AddressOf Canvas1_MouseEnter`to `Public Sub InitializeComponent()` in `MainWindow.g.i.vb` file. it didn't work

I have no idea how to implement mouse events. :(

so I tried to implement `MouseEnter` to the form it self, the event called properly.

Does it mean z-order matter?

Here is the xaml file

```
<Window x:Name="main" x:Class="MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="620.242" Width="827.423">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="575" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="807">
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="555" Margin="794,368,-774,-348" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="787" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

and the hanlder sub

```
    'this code generated automatically
     Private Sub Canvas1_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
        MessageBox.Show("event called")
    End Sub
```

How could I implement mouse event to my canvas?
Any help appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UI elements in WPF do not receive mouse events (without mouse capture) outside their rendered area. A Panel (like your Canvas) does not render anything outside the area of its child elements unless you define a non-null value for its `Background` property.

You may set a `Background` for your Canvas like shown below, which makes it render the entire area defined by its ActualWidth and ActualHeight with a transparent brush:

```
<Canvas x:Name="Canvas1" Background="Transparent"
        MouseEnter="Canvas1_MouseEnter" ... />
```

Comment: That's it...

that's fix my problem...

Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 0):

Your canvas does not have the MouseEnter event. Use it like this

```
<Grid>
    <Canvas HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="158" Margin="191,85,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" 
            Width="221" Background="#FF575757" MouseEnter="Canvas_MouseEnter"/>
</Grid>
```

And then the Sub for the Event:

```
Private Sub Canvas_MouseEnter(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs)
    MessageBox.Show("Hello?")
End Sub
```

Comment: Actually, I did give the mouse event properties...


But the problem is, I didn't give the `background` properties and you do give a background of the element...


Thanks, this one also work!